# Changing a variable in php file

Tags: php, html, forms

How to add values from `<input>` to `$var` in php file?

html

```
<input type="text" id="align" name="align"/>
```

php file

```
<?php
  $align="center";
?>
```

Comment: You're really going to have to give more detail. How and when do you want to use the value in input? Is the input part of a form? If so does it use the post or get method? Are the html and the PHP in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to post it and put it in a PHP variable?

Try this:

```
<form action="somephpfile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="align" value="center" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send!" />
</form>
```

somephpfile.php

```
    $align = $_POST['align'];
    echo $align;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the form action.

If your form that is holding your fields has an `action="post"` attribute then from the php side you have to use `$_POST['align']`. If you have set the action to `action="get"` then you have to use the `$_GET['align']`.

```
<?php

$align = $_POST['align'];

// OR

$align = $_GET['align'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just output it into the regular [HTML value attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp):

```
<input type="text" id="align" name="align" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($align); ?>" />
```

The [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) call is there to escape things like quotes, to avoid problems if your variable contains quotes, and to make your mark-up more standards-compliant.